# 16 byte alignment algorithm

Tags: pointers, alignment

I am studying the pytorch codebase and I saw [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv_v8.cpp#L38-L48) function that supposedly returns the alignment of a pointer to 16 bytes.

I fail to understand how this algorithm does that. In fact, I tried a few addresses that were already divisible by 16, and the function returns 64 for the alignment, which I think is wrong? Shouldn't it be 0?

Formerly, this function was written as

```
uint8_t getAlignment(const at::Tensor &t) {
  // alignment are in bytes
  uint8_t alignment = 1;
  uintptr_t address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(t.data_ptr());
  while (address % alignment == 0 && alignment < 16) alignment *= 2;

  return alignment;
}
```

This one also doesn't seem to be correct to me, but this is a bit outside of my territory so I am not sure if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously it can't return 0, since it can only return `alignment`. Alignment starts of at 1 and is doubled a few times, so it has to be a power of 2.

Any address that's divisible by 64 (aligned to 64 bytes) is also divisible by 16, since 64=16*4. E.g. if the address would be 17*64, then it's also equal to 68*16. And by that logic, anything is aligned to 1.

So when talking about alignment, you have to consider whether the context means "aligned to exactly N, at least N, or at most N". Alignment requirements are typically *at least N*, actual pointer values are aligned to *at most* N.

This particular function is none of those three. It tries to serve two functions at once: Is a pointer aligned to *at least* N=64, but if it's not, then how aligned is it precisely?

Comment: I have a couple of follow up questions. Why is this function trying to check divisibility by 64 instead of divisibility by 16 (I recall elsewhere in the code, it states that they call this function to get 16 byte alignment)? Assuming we want 64 byte alignment, can you clarify what is meant by "how aligned is it precisely?" Is it looking for how much needs to be added to the pointer address to get to the next address divisible by 64, or how far the current address has exceeded the previous address divislbe by 64, or neither of these?

Comment: @westcoaststudent: I certainly hope they're not checking if the result is ==16, but that they're checking if if is >=16. If not, you might have found a bug.

Comment: As for wanting "64 byte alignment" - if you wanted 64 byte alignment (address can be divided by 64, with remainder zero, `ptr % 64 = 0`), would you accept a pointer that's aligned to a 128 byte boundary (`ptr % 128 = 0`) or would you insist that `ptr % 128 = 1` ? There's nothing special that limits alignment to at most 64 bytes. The x86 CPU aligns pages to 406 bytes, for instance.

Comment: "Is it looking for how much needs to be added to the pointer address?" - no, it's effectively counting the number of trailing zero bits in the pointer, and returns `1<<(TrailingZeroBits)`. But it stops counting at 6 bits (`1<<6==64`)